# Reading an Old Philips Radio Manual with SCR rows

Tags: rf, radio, diagram

I've been looking at the manual for the Philips L4X26T radio and I have noticed that for each of the diagrams, there is a rather peculiar table with three rows of numbers labelled "S", "C" & "R" (please see the pictures below). Would someone know how you're supposed to read these? I would hazard a guess that they're there to show component values since the three letters correspond to inductance, capacitance and resistance respectively. (For some reason, whoever wrote this manual has decided to use "S" for inductance as opposed to the usual "L". If anyone knows the reason behind this, please let me know.)

On the 2nd page (the 1st picture here), there seems to also be another table with the labels "SK1", "SK2", "SK3", ... all the way up to "SK7". If anyone know what this table represents, please let me know.

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That scheme is a fast-finder index for the schematic components.

[image]

*Figure 1. Instead of having to search the schematic coils, capacitors and resistors can be quickly located by scanning the index across the top. Two lines are allowed for each component type - but this is barely enough judging by the results.*

It's a nice system.

For a long time now we have numbered components from left to right. This is easily done with automatic CAD numbering systems and so we don't have a need for the fast-finder. In the time of those schematics the design may have evolved and more components inserted as it progressed. The number sequence may give some clues as to what were later additions.

Philips is a Dutch company and Google Translate gives "spoel" as a Dutch translation of "coil" so I'm going to say that's what the 'S' is for.

The SKs are good old-fashioned radio buttons.

[image]

*Figure 2. Random eBay interlocking radio button switches.*

The diagram gives the mechanical layout and probably some interlocking and switching information. The individual contacts are cross-referenced to their contacts in the schematic.

"Switch" in Dutch is "schakelaar" so that will do me!

Answer (score 4):

These bars help you to locate specific components in the schematic and on the PCB.

Example: locate R36

In the bar with "R"on the left, find the number "36" then in the schematic R36 is below that "36" (it is connected to the emitter of Tr.6).

R => Resistor

C => Capacitor

S => inductor or transformer

It works in an identical way for the PCB.